# How to fix 'Original error: 'Command '' exited with code 1'; Stderr: ''; Code: '1''

Tags: java, appium

I'm new in the appium automation testing and i've tried to run set of code using appium and java but this error always returned to me although I've installed appium and nodejs latest version and i'd like to run this below code. 
I've tried to run the below code on windows 10 with appium 1.13.0 and i've installed all prerequisite such as node js and appium desktop client

```
package andriod;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class StartApplication {

    private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping_2019-09-11.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
        caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Redmi");   
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9.0");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,"60");
        caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
     }

}
```

I expect the code will run successfully but the error message returned to me as same as below

> Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s dd8fa21 shell pm install -g /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/728413456b86856a2003edeb524d6bd577ca6418.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: ''; Code: '1'

Comment: Your first line is misspelled BTW

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: I run this through eclipse. i've run the main class and actually appium server is running

Comment: and I used redmi note 7 android version 9.0

Comment: Your package and activity parameters are suspect.  I also wonder if your app filename is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the command itself, may be `appium@beta` doesn't have this configured yet.

If you try to run the command on it's own: `adb -P 5037 -s dd8fa21 shell pm install -g /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/728413456b86856a2003edeb524d6bd577ca6418.apk`

you will see output says: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]`

The test flag `-t` is missing from the command generated by appium espresso server.

I solved it by manually installing apk running:

`adb -P 5037 -s dd8fa21 shell pm install -t -g /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/728413456b86856a2003edeb524d6bd577ca6418.apk`

Answer (score 0):

1- First check if the appium is running or not.

2- If yes, you should know that sometimes Node.js could not talk to **127.0.0.1:4723**, So use **0.0.0.0:4723** instead. Remember to change this in both code (DesiredCapabilities) and appium setting.

3- "udid" parametre is required for desired capabilities

4- You should keep the structure of code like the following. Also using this 3 notations is required: (@BeforeMethod , @Test, @AfterMethod)

Something like this:

```
 import <...>
    .
    .

    public class sample {  //this is the main class. You shouldn't define it as static or void so you must not have main methode
    //define variables you will be use during the test        
public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
        public WebDriverWait wait;
        public Dimension size;
        public String destDir;
        public DateFormat dateFormat;
        .
        .
        .
    //define the methodes you will be use during the test 
    public (swipe) {
    ... };
    public (takeScreenShot) {
    ...};

@BeforeMethod

    public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S7 API 26");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "ce0217124184c72505"); //DeviceId from "adb devices" command
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "app_packageName"); // Your app packageName
        caps.setCapability("appActivity","app_first_activity"); // The first activity of app. You can use "Apk Info2" application to find this
        caps.setCapability("noReset","false");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}

@Test
     public void test () throws Exception {

    //Test commands
    }

@AfterMethod

    public void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the problem from my mobile redmi, I changed the device and the problem is resolved